# How should I handle rounding during tests with SQLLite3 in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, integration-testing

In my schema.rb, I have this field defined with 2 decimal places. It works fine in DEV which uses PostgreSQL, but for testing, it uses SQLLite3 and shows all decimals.

```
t.decimal  "usdBalance",                 precision: 8,  scale: 2

assert_equal u1.usdBalance.to_f, 9.40  # $10 - $2 + $1 + $0.40

1) Failure:
Expected: 9.405
  Actual: 9.4
```

Here is the controller code being tested which calculates the value and saves it in the database. The only thing of significance is that a floating point number with more than 2 digits is being saved. In PostgreSQL, it is rounded, but in SQLLite3 the full precision is kept.

```
    usdShare = usdSum / count
    model.each do |m|
      user = m.user.lock!
      user.usdBalance += usdShare
      user.save!
```

Is it best to manually round floats before saving them? That is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Why the `to_f`?  Why not compare decimals?

Comment: @jcm Because the field is treated as a BigDecimal by Rails, and `assert_equal` does not convert it to a numeric format for comparison. It will say something like `Expected: #<BigDecimal:5ca6900,'0.94E1',18(18)>, Actual: 9.4`.

Comment: I used `user.usdBalance = (floatingPointNumber * 100).truncate / 100.0 # round` in the controller code which calculates and saves the values for now. It will round down to the nearest 2 decimal places.

Comment: Can you post your code?  I'm not sure why you're storing decimals then using floats in the code.  Also, note that Ruby convention uses snake_case for variable names.

Comment: Which part of the code do you want me to post? I posted the schema.rb, the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` assertion, and the log output.

Comment: The code being tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You commented that

> It will round down to the nearest 2 decimal places.

Actually, it will round to the nearest floating-point value. Over the full range of floating-point values, it will only rarely hit a values that has only two digits to the right of the decimal point.

For example, this expression doesn't evaluate to 9999999.2. It returns 9999999.19

```
( 9999999.2 * 100 ).truncate / 100.0
```

But while learning how to deal with floating point is important for most programmers, it's really beside the point in this question.

What you *really* want to do is to run integration tests against PostgreSQL, not against SQLite. Because you're not integrating your code into a production environment that runs SQLite; you're integrating your code into a production environment that runs PostgreSQL.

Personally, I develop *only* against the production environment. If we're using PostgreSQL in production, I develop against PostgreSQL.

Comment: The fix I inserted rounds down, because of .truncate: `(floatingPointNumber * 100).truncate / 100.0`. PostgreSQL does round to the nearest value though. I'm using Postgres in DEV and PROD, but SQLLite in TEST. I've never run unit tests with different databases before. I thought SQLLite was sufficient but I guess not.  I didn't want to set up another PG DB just for testing when I was learning Rails testing, but I think that's the best idea. I thought maybe my schema/model/assertions might be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you truncate doesn't matter. What I said about floating-point values still holds. SQLite isn't SQL. (There's more to SQL than SELECT syntax.) But it's close enough for many applications.

Comment: See [#truncate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-truncate). `(3.145 * 100).truncate / 100.0 = 3.14`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. See Knuth, vol 2.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it help to make `9.40` a `BigDecimal` first, then compare those?

```
assert_equal u1.usdBalance, 9.40.to_d
```

Comment: No, because the value stored in the SQLLite3 database is 9.405 (without manually rounding it), even though the field is defined as scale: 2. So comparing BigDecimal(9.405) == BigDecimal(9.40) will still fail.